# How to get Outlook Redemption.dll to self register during a click once install?

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

can't seem to figure it out... I need to copy Redemption.dll to a folder (eg. C:\Program Files (x86)\Redemption) and then regsvr32 it.

I also need this to happen if Redemption.dll already exists on a users machine (i want to replace and re-register it with the dll included in my click once installation)

btw, this is a vsto outlook plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create an msi which all it did was have the Redemption.dll self registering and installed it via group policy on all machines in our office..

then just deployed the click once app normally without the prerequisite.

I've also found out that if a click-once app is updating that it will NOT re-check for prerequisites, you must have the user run the setup.exe that a click-once deployment deploys.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a batch file and package it with your setup project. and  using custom action, you can execute this batch file which will do the job of registering /unregistering  redemption for you.